# SyntaxError in Spyder Profiler on a line that does not exist?

Tags: python, syntax-error, spyder

Running a fairly long code (approx 7000 lines) that reads multiple excel files, computes some stuff with pandas, produces multiple excel file outputs and about 40 graphs with matplotlib pyplot. The code makes it through half the script, then suddenly switches from ipython shell to the profiler to give me this error message. The thing is, I don't even have a line 9001. So, I have no idea what, how, and where to fix it.

Running Python 2.7 on Spyder editor, Windows 10, 16GB RAM. See the above link for the screenshot of the error message and let me know if you need more info!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\base_frontend_mixin.py", line 163, in _dispatch
handler(msg)
  File "C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\namespacebrowser.py", line 188, in _handle_execute_reply
self.handle_exec_method(msg)
  File "C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 225, in handle_exec_method
properties = ast.literal_eval(data['text/plain'])
  File "C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Users\eh\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 9001
...}
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

UPDATE:

Just tried one of my old (previously working!) codes, doesn't matter what I run I keep getting the same error code now.

Comment: The line 9001 is from a **library** (see the `lib` in the file path) file. So you are calling the library the wrong way (or at least in a way the library is not expecting). But since you cannot provide us the code, we cannot help fix the code.

Comment: **Do not post pictures of code, or of tracebacks. Copy and paste it into the question itself**

Comment: Sorry, I'll remember for next time!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i saw the lib part, but the line 9001 is from a certain File"<unknown>" not the previous C:\users\... ones that's why i was confused

Comment: @ElHi: that's probably because it works with an *abstract syntax tree* (the name `ast`). Nevertheless I would walk up in your traceback to your own code and look what call you make. There is definitely something wrong there.

Comment: The line number is referring to the string being passed to ``ast.literal_eval()``.  I would guess that it was read from a configuration file that has become corrupted.

Comment: Please update to Spyder **3.1.2** and try again. This error should be fixed in that version.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba So I have updated to Spyder 3.1.2 and the problem still persists, no matter what code I run or even if I try a simple define variable, print variable test in the ipython shell i get the invalid syntax errors...?

Comment: I figured it out! There was a capitalisation error in some folder name deep within the Anaconda package - renamed the folder and it's all working perfectly now! YAY!!!

Comment: Great!! Glad you've found the solution!